# Query google images with copy right free filter using requests/urllib

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to query images with copy right free filter. Even though the url leads to the right settings in my code, for some reason the page that is read by both urllib and requests is the first few images without the copy right free and size filter. If anyone can help with this I would greatly appreciate it.

code:

```
#%%
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

url = 'https://google.com/search?q='
input = 'cat'
#string: tbm=isch --> means image search
#tbs=isz:m --> size medium
#il:cl --> copy right free(i think)
url = url+input+'&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:m%2Cil:cl'
print(url)
html = urlopen(Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Google Chrome'}))
'''with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    html = response.read()
    print(html)'''
#print(str(r.content))

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify)
#using soup to find all img tags
results = soup.find_all('img')
str_result = str(results)
print(str_result)
lst_result = str_result.split(',')
#trying to get the very first link for the images with the appropriate settings
link = lst_result[4].split(' ')[4].split('"')[1]
#print(link)
# writing into the appropriate testing file, to be changed
file = open('.img1.png','wb')
get_img = requests.get(link)
file.write(get_img.content)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import re, json

extentions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg']

# determine image extention (not guaranteed, some links lack the extension)
def extention(url): 
    # or use the "imghdr" package to determine the extention
    for ext in extentions:
        if url.endswith(f'.{ext}'):
            return ext 
    return '.UNKNOWN'        

URL = 'https://google.com/search'

params = {
'q': 'cat', # search term
'tbm': 'isch',
'tbs': 'isz:m,il:cl'
}

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.3'
}

r = requests.get(URL, params=params, headers=headers)

html = r.text
matches = re.findall('data:\[(?!\])(.*?)],\ sideChannel', html) # the data lives in a script, not in <img> elements (initially)
data = json.loads(f'[{matches[1]}]')    

images = []    
for image in data[31][0][12][2]: # the data structure may change some day, but its consistent between requests as of now
    if type(image) is list:
        try:
            images.append(image[1][3][0])
        except:
            pass
images = list(dict.fromkeys(images)) # remove duplicate links    

# retrive and save the first image's data
print(images[0])
imgdata = requests.get(images[0], headers=headers).content
with open(f'img.{extention(images[0])}', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(imgdata)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are only so helpful. This particular answer would benefit greatly from an explanation as to how it solves the issues in the OP.